# ClassCastException when comparing Dates?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am using GXT/ExtGWT. I have below code which compares two dates.

```
private DateField startDateField = new DateField();
private DateField endDateField = new DateField();
Date date = new Date();

CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(date, -1);
startDateField.setValue(date);
endDateField.setValue(new Date());

Date fromDate = startDateField.getValue();
Date toDate = endDateField.getValue();    

Date differenceBetweenDates = new Date(fromDate.getTime());
CalendarUtil.addMonthsToDate(differenceBetweenDates, 6);

if (differenceBetweenDates.before(toDate)) {
    MessageBox.alert("Alert","Date range should not exceed six months", null);
    return false;
} else{ 
    return true;
}
```

Here in datefields fromdate I selected as `0012-12-30` and todate as `0012-12-31`.

When the line `differenceBetweenDates.before(toDate)` is executed, I am getting below exception. Please help me. Am i doing any wrong here?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.util.calendar.JulianCalendar$Date cannot be cast to sun.util.calendar.Gregorian$Date
```

Comment: Which line number are you getting the exception at?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. below is the line where i'm getting an exception.if (differenceBetweenDates.before(toDate)) .

Answer (score 3):

According to http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Date.java.html, java.util.Date contains this code:

```
private static final BaseCalendar getCalendarSystem(long utc) {
  // Quickly check if the time stamp given by `utc' is the Epoch
  // or later. If it's before 1970, we convert the cutover to
  // local time to compare.
  if (utc >= 0
    || utc >= GregorianCalendar.DEFAULT_GREGORIAN_CUTOVER
        - TimeZone.getDefaultRef().getOffset(utc)) {
    return gcal;
 }
 return getJulianCalendar();
```

}

So it looks to me that because you are putting year in as 0012 not 2012, it chooses JulianCalendar.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for your reply. Please advise me what should be the better solution in this case. Thanks

Comment: Change the select options to 2012 instead of 12 or add 2000 to the year in the two date variables.

Comment: Hi Paul,The problem is datefield is editable,so user can edit any date..the only validation we have is date should be in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: First thing to check is that you don't see the exception if you enter in 2012-12-30 and 2012-12-31. Can you add validation rules or would it be possible to limit the users to two digits for year (which you could add 2000 to)? I'm not familiar with GWT.

Comment: Hi Paul, if enter above values it takes ..no exception...if i enter any date after year 1583 then it works..if i enter any date before 1583 then it gives an excpetion...

Comment: From Date class: private static final BaseCalendar getCalendarSystem(int year) {
 if (year >= 1582) {
     return gcal;
 }
 return getJulianCalendar();
    }//i think here something is happening

Comment: Yes that year matches GregorianCalendar.DEFAULT_GREGORIAN_CUTOVER. Do toDate().getYear() after you assign it and see if it is less than 1583. If it is less than 100, you may be able to make an assumption that the user means 1900 + the year or 2000 plus the year - e.g. 60-99 is probably 1960-1999, 00-59 is probably 2000-2059. This may be risky depending on the app's purpose. If it is between 100 and 1583 then I would imagine it is an invalid date and you can throw an exception back to the user. If dates between 100 and 1583 are valid, you will have to write some more code for that case without

Comment: ... without using the before() method. last message should read "do toDate.getYear() after you do Date toDate = endDateField.getValue(); Do same for fromDate too.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but for a different use case (the Dates do come from user input, yet the data source is an Excel table).

A very simple workaround did the trick for me:

```
private static boolean isBefore(Date firstDate, Date secondDate) {
    return firstDate.getTime() < secondDate.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date parsing has some problem. Something thinks you intend to represent time according to Caesar's Julian calendar! Unless you're Orthodox I doubt this is the intent. `endDateField` has some problem inside that is manipulating dates with the entirely wrong calendar.