# What does below code means in java.util.Date? What is the difference between these calendars?

Tags: java, algorithm, date, time, calendar

In `java.util.Date` I have seen below code.

```
private static final BaseCalendar getCalendarSystem(int year) {
    if (year >= 1582) {
        return gcal;
    }
    return getJulianCalendar();
    }
```

What does this mean? I have this issue [ClassCastException when comparing Dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831545/classcastexception-when-comparing-dates)

Answer (score 5):

That means that in year 1582 by pope Gregory a calendar reform was made. Before this date - Julian calendar, after - Gregorian.

In Julian calendar we had a leap year if its number can be divided by 4.
In Gregorian - if its number can be divided by 4, minus these years that can be divided by 100 plus these that can be divided by 400.

more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar)

A more precise calendar could be made if this rule with hundreds would be repeated with thousands, but it was not done and eventually the calendar will collect so large error against the real yearly cycle, that a new reform will be needed. But it is the problem of thousands years - in one thousand years a 3/4 of day is lost.

Obviously this is the reason why they started the new calendar with the correction of one day less, than it should be because of the difference between Gregorian and Julian calendar only. During the second thousand years, we'll lose a day more... already now the spring equinox point happens more often in 20-21 of March instead of 21-22 as it was 400 years ago.

Comment: +1:  Different countries adopted the Calendar in different years.  Some as late at the 1900s.  The USA adopted the Gregorian Calendar in 1752 retrospectively. c.f. Britain which dropped 12 days. This means dates before that year were re-dated e.g. George Washington was born on February 11, 1731 but this date was changed to February 22, 1732 after adoption. Orthodox churchs still use the Julian calendar to determine Christmas for example today.

Comment: Yes, Russia reformed in 1918. The Russian Ortodox Church has Julian calendar till now. According to it, the first day of the new year is tomorrow (13 Jan). Happy New Year! :-). In Russia it is a non-official holiday till now and is named: OLD NEW YEAR.

Comment: Greece adopted it in 1924, However there are those who still use the Julian calendar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_Old_Calendarists  Even in the USA some people continued to use the Julian Calendar for more than a century after it was officially adopted.

Comment: In the Julian Calendar the first day of the year was March 25th being 9 months before December 25th. This is the reason September (Sept means 7), October (Oct means 8), November (Nona means ninth) and December (Deci mean 10) have the names they do.  Julius Caeser (who added a day to July and named it after himself) wasn't Christian, so this date had a pre-Christian meaning.  His successor, Augustus Caesar (who wasn't actually related to his adopted father) named August after himself and added a day.  This left February (the last month of the year) shorter than all the rest.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey. Sorry, in 1752 the error of Julian calendar made 1732 div 100 -1732 div 400 -3 =17 -4-3=10. (-3 there is because the "correct" equinox according to Catholic Church was in 325y.) So, the correction should be 10 days, not 12. And the correction for Washington birthday should be the same, not 11 days. Of these three corrections : 10,11,12 days only one should be correct I am afraid. Hmmm... We could compare gcal against getJulianCalendar in java.util.Date :-). According to Wiki it is 11. But I don't understand why wiki proposes H-(H div 4) -2 formula...

Comment: Oh, I see, it was a DECISION (of the church counsil, not wiki).

Comment: In the year 1752, the correction was 10 days. When Britain & USA adopted the calendar, the correction was 11 days (not 12),  The difference NOW is 12 days.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey. Difference NOW is 13 days :-) Look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Difference_between_Gregorian_and_Julian_calendar_dates if you don't believe me. Thank you that you are on my side against the offocial formula, though :-)

Comment: So new years day is Jan 14th.

Comment: In any case, comparing Julian and Gregorian calendars is even more confusing than it appears. ;)

Comment: No, the year 2000 is leap in both calendars

Comment: Yes, astrometry is terribly intricated. And law, too. And in calendar problem we have them both. Happy Old New Year :-)

Comment: Just reading about Russia's adoption after the October Revolution, which occurred in November due to the switch. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6674/discussion-between-gangnus-and-peter-lawrey)

Answer (score 0):

The currently used calendar is the Gregorian calendar. It was introduced in 1582 to fix problems with the year length in the previous (Julian) calendar.

Therefore it's wrong to use the `GregorialCalendar` class for dates before 1582, and Java will implicitly work with the class `JulianCalendar` instead.

Comment: The start of the year also changed to Jan 1st. The first day of the years was March 25th (being nine months before December 25th)

Comment: Hi Michael, is it possible to convert date of GregorialCalendar to JulianCalendar ? if user enters dates as 1500-04-30 and 1500-12-31 then how can i compare them? my condition is diffrence between both dates should not exceed 6 months as explained in my other link.